# Can't find OXReserved on Disk Utiity

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, disk-utility, mojave

[image]I tried to delete OXReserved in order to delete Bootcamp using Disk Utility in Mojave, but I can't see OXReserved[image] in Disk Utility. Is it the tiny slice on the pie chart next to the Bootcamp slice? Cuz I do have the option to "minus" Bootcamp, but the tiny slice next to it has "minus" greyed out. Thanks for your help. Larry

Comment: The Disk Utility application is notorious for being inaccurate. Before issuing an answer, I would prefer you post the output from the Terminal application command `diskutil list`.

Comment: Hi David, thanks for your reply. I posted the output of diskutil list: I hope it's visible. Thanks for your help. Larry

Comment: Please don't paste a screen shot as the text contained isn't searchable.  Paste the raw output and use `code` formatting to style the text.

Comment: Hi Allan, thank you for the instructions and sorry for my mistake. I hope this will be ok:

Comment: I copied and pasted by I get this message: too long by 495 characters ...maybe I am too dumb to post in this forum...? :)

Answer (score 1):

You no long have a OXReserved partition. The partition shown in you question is the Windows Recovery partition. This partition is created when Windows is installed using the Boot Camp Assistant. (Although, the partition can also be created when someone installs Windows without using the Boot Camp Assistant.) A correct installation of Windows should include a BOOTCAMP partition and a Windows Recovery partition.

To remove the Windows Recovery partition using the Disk Utility, you would first have to remove the BOOTCAMP partition.

> Note: Normally, the Boot Camp Assistant is used to remove Windows.